# Alternatives to Graph theory?

Tags: social-network-analysis

- I was planning to use a graph theoretic and page-rank approach to finding the most influential person in an organization.

  > Influential person is someone who drives a lot of activity in the
  >   organization. When he assigns a task, most people do it. When he sends
  >   a mail, most people reply to him. When he assigns some training, most
  >   people do it.

  But there is one drawback to using graph theory here. For example, say Person A is very influential, and Person B has just joined an organization and works under A. B puts in a leave request and sends it A for approval. A approves the leave request. This seems contradictory, since A is very influential but A responded to B. According to graph theory, wouldn't this make Person B also very influential? This approach would give very bad results.

  **How can i overcome this limitation? Can anyone suggest an alternative approach?**

---

- I am using number of interactions to calculate an `affinity scores` between two users. Based on this, I suggest what content should be shown to a user (like FaceBook does). User A responds to User B most of the time.  so (A->B) has a high affinity score. So, in user B's newsfeed I intend to show content coming from User A.

  **is there a better way than just counting number of interactions?**

  If two users A & C have same affinity scores with B, if A is more influential than B, A's content will be shown first to user B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### According to graph theory, wouldn't this make Person B also very influential?

No. You need to think about how to set up your graph first and then go further. In this case your graph is not simple but both **weighted** and **directed** thus handling a request of B by A neither reduces A's influence nor improves B's. Because the weights of directed edges are determining the influence.

### Is there a better way than just counting number of interactions?

[*Community Detection*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01523) or what computer scientists call [*Graph Clustering*](http://dollar.biz.uiowa.edu/~street/graphClustering.pdf). If you do not have to limit yourself to hierarchies, you can extract communities who have the most interaction and share suggestions inside the community.

Comment: In a weighted and directed graph, what is the best measure of Influence? Eigen centrality, Betweeness Centrality or Weighted Avg. Degress, In-Degree

Comment: All centrality measures are actually talking about the same concept but with different languages. The best is to take a sample data and see which one works better for your purpose. Please note that 1) Not all of them have a wighted directed version and 2) If your graph is big then the computational complexity matters a lot (e.g. Eigen centrality is not comfortable for gigantic graphs)